# PHP's ftp_put not reporting error to screen

Tags: php

I'm using PHP's FTP functions and I'm having a problem with ftp_put.

Any files under 40MB upload fine through my script, but anything over 40MB doesn't. On the server I'm working on I'm not getting a PHP error to screen to report why.

I'm just wondering if anyone has any suggestions for why it won't print an error, because that is what I need to figure out why it's not uploading.

Supplementary info...

- PHP errors are turned on
- Errors aren't suppressed with @ftp_put
- PHP.INI allows 2GB file uploads

Comment: In what mode is your ftp connection?

Comment: What have you got set to "turn errors on"? What is you memory_limit set at?

Comment: This may help you recieve errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death?rq=1

Comment: There's no error being shown, but what does your *log* say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use error_get_last() to print the last error.

Answer (score 0):

Upload limit does not matter here. It's probably a running memory problem. Try the non-bloquant function to send the file chunked:
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ftp-nb-put.php